# CSS Selectors for Nested UL LI

Tags: css, nested, css-selectors, html-lists, pseudo-class

I am trying to style specific elements of a nested list, without using classes. Specifically, looking at the example below, how would I style ONLY the 'SubList Item' elements with a colored background, but NOT any of the 'Main List', 'SuperSub List' and 'SuperDuperSub List' items?

```
<div>
   <ul>
      <li><a>Main List Item</a></li>
      <li><a>Main List Item</a>
         <ul>
            <li><a>SubList Item</a></li>
         </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a>Main List Item</a></li>
      <li><a>Main List Item</a></li>
      <li><a>Main List Item</a>
         <ul>
            <li><a>SubList Item</a></li>
            <li><a>SubList Item</a>
               <ul>
                  <li><a>SuperSub List</a></li>
                  <li><a>SuperSub List</a>
                     <ul>
                        <li><a>SuperDuperSub List</a></li>
                        <li><a>SuperDuperSub List</a></li>
                     </ul>
                  </li>
               </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a>SubList Item</a></li>
            <li><a>SubList Item</a></li>
         </ul>  
      </li>
      <li><a>Main List Item</a></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Okay I read it. Next instruction please.

Comment: @lang It's not an instruction for you. Just a suggestion from my side. It's always best practice to add your full code(CSS), People in SO want to know first what did you tried so far. I have seen some downvote in your question that's why I have shared the link with you so that you can add your minimal code. If you think I'm did anything wrong here, Sorry for that

Answer (score 1):

This was a way to do it based off your markup although I personally would say use classes if possible.

```
div > ul > li > ul > li > a {
  background: #000;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I knew I was close, and that I needed to add the div and the a elements to make it work. It seems like unfortunately without classes it wouldn't be possible to target just the li elements though. Agreed?

Comment: Putting a background on the li. You will target a specific li element, but because there are uls contained inside of it the background will cover the contained area, the text comes from from the a tag.